# Missing reference exception in Unity after instantiating multiple GameObject prefabs and deleting original

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am currently making a Breakout style game and have 2 "Power-ups" that are giving me some trouble. I have a double-ball and triple-ball power-ups that instantiate 1 or 2 extra balls from an original ball prefab.

Everything works fine as long as the original ball is still in the scene but after the original ball from the scene is deleted (The ball is destroyed after it hits the bottom of the screen but the game continues if the cloned balls are still in play and the "Ball Count" is not 0) I get the following error in the lines containing the Instantiate function in the double and triple power-up cases:

> MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'Transform' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.

The portion of my Paddle Code handles the powers on collision between the paddle and the powerup is as follows:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    GameObject[] ArrayOfBalls = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Ball");

    switch (collision.tag)
    {
        case "Life Powerup" :
            Debug.Log("hit " + collision.name);
            gm.UpdateLives(1);
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            break;

        case "Speed PowerUp":

            for (int i = 0; i<ArrayOfBalls.Length; i++)
            {
                ball ballscript = ArrayOfBalls[i].GetComponent < ball>();
                if (ballscript.rb.velocity.magnitude > 7.5f)
                {
                    CancelInvoke("NormalSpeed");
                    Invoke("NormalSpeed", 5f);

                }
                else if (ballscript.rb.velocity.magnitude <= 7.5f)
                {
                    ballscript.rb.velocity = new Vector2(ballscript.rb.velocity.x * 1.5f, ballscript.rb.velocity.y * 1.5f);
                    Invoke("NormalSpeed", 5f);
                }

            }

            //If another powerup is collected call to function to slow down is cancelled and started with new delay


            Debug.Log("hit " + collision.name);
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            break;

        case "Shrink PowerDown":

            gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3( 0.25f, 0.4f, 1f);
            Invoke("NormalSize", 15);

            Debug.Log("hit " + collision.name);
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            break;

        case "Expand PowerUp":

            gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3( 0.55f, 0.4f, 1f);
            Invoke("NormalSize", 5f);
            Debug.Log("hit " + collision.name);
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            break;

        case "Double PowerUp":
            for (int i = 0; i < ArrayOfBalls.Length; i++)
            {
                ball ballscript = ArrayOfBalls[i].GetComponent<ball>();
                Transform Doubleclone = Instantiate(PrefabBall, new Vector3(ballscript.rb.position.x + 0.1f, ballscript.rb.position.y + 0.1f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
                Doubleclone.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(ballscript.rb.velocity.x, ballscript.rb.velocity.y);
                gm.UpdateBallCount(1);


            }
            Debug.Log("hit " + collision.name);
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            break;

        case "Triple PowerUp":
            for (int i = 0; i < ArrayOfBalls.Length; i++)
            {

                ball ballscript = ArrayOfBalls[i].GetComponent<ball>();
                Transform Tripleclone = Instantiate(PrefabBall, new Vector3(ballscript.rb.position.x + 0.1f, ballscript.rb.position.y + 0.1f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
                Transform Tripleclone2 = Instantiate(PrefabBall, new Vector3(ballscript.rb.position.x - 0.1f, ballscript.rb.position.y - 0.1f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
                Tripleclone.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(ballscript.rb.velocity.x, ballscript.rb.velocity.y);
                Tripleclone2.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(ballscript.rb.velocity.x, ballscript.rb.velocity.y);
                gm.UpdateBallCount(2);

            }

            Debug.Log("hit " + collision.name);
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            break;

    }
```

I don't know what a good fix for this would be and appreciate any ideas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see the code where the balls are destroyed or your setup but in your question it sounds to me like in `PrefabBall` you referenced the original ball from the **Scene**.

So when you `Destroy()` it then `PrefabBall` will ne `null` ofcourse.

---

How about rather having an actual prefab in the `Assets` instead of referencing a Scene object? I guess you didn't do this because you directly wanted to clone it's current properties coming from the powerups along with it. But there are other options for that (e.g. copying them like you did with the rigidbody settings or having the powerups stored as `static` values)

---

Alternatively only disable the "lost" balls

```
ball.gameObject.SetActive(false);
```

instead of destroying them. This way it stays intact but isn't available for the game anymore. You only would have to make sure to enable instantiated balls like

```
Doubleclone.gameObject.SetActive(true);
```

---

As a sidenote there are also some efficiency problems I'ld like to note here

You all the time use

```
ball ballscript = ArrayOfBalls[i].GetComponent<ball>();
```

It would be way more efficient to instead directly use

```
ball[] ArrayOfBalls = FindObjectsOfType<ball>();
```

or as a complete alternative to `Find` use a

```
public static readonly List<ball> ArrayOfBalls = new List<ball>();
```

make the type of `PrefabBall` rather `ball` and now everytime you instantiate a new ball add it to the list

```
ball Doubleclone = Instantiate(PrefabBall, ....);
ArrayOfBalls.Add(Doubleclone);
```

and everytime **before** you `Destroy()` a ball remove it from the list frist

```
ArrayOfBalls.Remove(ball);
Destroy(ball.gameObject);
```

On this way your `ArrayOfBalls` is always up-to-date by itself.

**And** you can easely get the current ball count globaly:

```
YourScriptType.ArrayOfBalls.Count
```